# Where to find postgis.jar to query the PostGIS/PostgreSQL database from Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgis

I would like to query the PostGIS/PostgreSQL database from Java.

PostgreSQL 9.4 is installed.

PostGIS 2.1 Bundle for PostgreSQL 9.4 is installed through Stack Builder.

The PostGIS manual says: "Java clients can access PostGIS "geometry" objects in the PostgreSQL database either directly as text representations or using
the JDBC extension objects bundled with PostGIS. In order to use the extension objects, the "postgis.jar" file must be in your CLASSPATH along with the "postgresql.jar" JDBC driver package."

Where do I find the postgis.jar file?

Comment: have you install post gis along with postgreySQL??

Answer (score 0):

You can get jar from below links.

PostGIS.jar -> http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpostgisjar.htm

Postgresql.jar -> http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjdbcpostgresqljar.htm

Comment: I suppose https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html is a better location for getting the correct postgresql.jar?

Comment: Is java2s.com a trustworthy source? Would that give me the most recent postgis.jar file?

Comment: Yes this is trustworthy source and for a version you need to check and one more thing is if you have installed postgis along with postgreysql then i think postgreysql.jar will enough to work further.

Comment: the java2s location above does not have current drivers for postgis. Try here: http://postgis.net/stuff/

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to get the sources from a [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgis/postgis-jdbc/) and include it in my POM.

Comment: not at all current. The most current version is available at http://postgis.net/stuff/, unfortunately.

Comment: @AnatolyG you are right, the versions are not up to date. Missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Here some alternatives:

- Jar: http://postgis.net/stuff/
- Maven: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.postgis
- From source: https://github.com/postgis/postgis-java/

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use these dependencies instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.postgis</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${driver.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.postgis/postgis-geometry -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.postgis</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgis-geometry</artifactId>
    <version>${driver.version}</version>
</dependency>
```